# PyQgis getting attribute values from specific features without StopIteration exception

Tags: qgis, python

I have been trying to access the values of the attributes of certain features in a vector layer. I have tried to to as they suggest in [How to read the attribute values using PyQGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/54057/how-to-read-the-attribute-values-using-pyqgis/54059) and [Getting feature attribute description with pyqgis?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/256620/getting-feature-attribute-description-with-pyqgis), but whenever i try to define the feature with next(), i get StopIteration exception. This stops my program as if it was an error. I have been working on it for quite some time, but I haven't been able to find a way around it.

Is there a way to get attribute values from specific features of the vector layer without getting stoped by "StopIteration"?

I am working in QGIS 2.18

EDIT, Code snippit:

```
for i in range(0, len(vaiable)):
    request = QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterFid(i)
    iterator = layer.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterFid(i))
    feature = next(iterator)
    #feature = layer.getFeatures(request).next()
```

I have tried with both iterator and request, with but StopIterator is raised when trying to assign "feature" in both cases

Comment: Hi Kasper, can you add the code you are using for this?

Comment: Of course, done so in edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite hard to know, what exactly you have in `vaiable`. I assume it's an array, and given the array is `[1,2,3]`, i would iterate over 0,1,2.

Your code is based on the assumption, that there is a feature for each of these three ids (0, 1 and 2), but the StopIteration tells us that this assumption does not hold true. At some point, the code tries to get a feature on an empty iterator.

The following code will help to get more information which ID is not there. If you just want to ignore non-existent features, remove the `raise`.

```
for i in range(0, len(vaiable)):
    request = QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterFid(i)
    iterator = layer.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterFid(i))
    try:
        feature = next(iterator)
    except StopIteration:
        print('No feature with id {} found in dataset').format(i)
        raise
    #feature = layer.getFeatures(request).next()
```

To check which ids the features on the layer have, use this code:

```
print(', '.join(str(f.id()) for f in layer.getFeatures()))
```

Comment: The variable changes and is supposed to be an feature for each of the ids. I did try the test, and the exception is raised already at id 0. I have been trying this in qgis console with different numbers, and StopIteration is always stopping the code

Comment: What is the output of `print(', '.join(str(f.id()) for f in layer.getFeatures()))`? That will print all the ids which are available on the layer.

Comment: It prints out a long list of ascending numbers (6, 16, 28, 47, 55, 77, 91, 99, 129 ... ).
So, the feature ids doesn't necessarily start at 0 or 1 then? I suppose that's where I went wrong. I will rethink the code with this information. Thank you for your help